How to drive a piezoelectric air pump with DC
I have a small 2 watt piezoelectric aquarium air pump, which uses a piezo device instead of an electromagnet, to move a diaphragm.  There is a bit of circuitry which seems to convert 220v to 110v, but otherwise it seems to connect the mains power supply directly to the piezo and resonate at 50Hz.
I'd like to hack it to make it operate from a USB power supply. I could match the 50Hz with an oscillator circuit, but I'm interested in knowing if I need to boost the voltage? Is there anything else I need to be aware of? I know with magnetic systems there are complications around inductive resistance, back-emf, voltage spikes, etc. but I don't know anything about piezos.

Piezo actuators are basically high-impedance, high-voltage devices. To get 2 W from older USB 2.0 ports, though, is pushing their limit (new USB 3.0 and later can provide far more power). An inverter with 80% or better efficiency might just make it from USB 2.0 port.

It would be a project!  here is a link to a reference design that might get you on the right track https://www.digikey.com/en/pdf/m/microchip-technology/an2104-piezoelectric-micropump-driver-reference-design

A piezo fan uses very little current.  However, that multiplies as you derive it from a lower and lower voltage source.  Without getting into RMS versus peak versus peak-to-peak volts, stepping 5 Vdc up to 110 Vac is a factor of 22x.  So if the fan requires 18 mA to operate, the power circuit will draw more than 400 mA from the 5 V source.
The circuit is called a boost converter, and in round numbers they are the least efficient of all of the switching power converter topologies.  At this power level, an alternative is a small power transformer driven "backwards".  That is, you put a 5 V sine or square wave into the secondary, and 110 V falls out the primary.  One nice thing about this approach is that there are zero electronic components or wiring on the high voltage side of the circuit.
To start, we have to have the current the fan draws at the desired operating voltage.  Photos of the fan, supply, AC converter - whatever - are important.  The supply might be overrated, so more important is any information on the fan itself; often there is a voltage/current sticker near the power entry connector or wires.
Once you have that, (and this hurts), this sounds like a job for a 555.  There is a simple circuit that takes just one resistor and one capacitor to produce a 50/50 square wave output, and the standard (non-CMOS) 555 has an extra-beefy output stage.  It is not very efficient, so the power transformer will need to have a very low secondary rating.
How married are you to using a USB power source for this?  Much better would be a 9 V or 12 V wall wart, like from an old telephone answering machine, internet router, etc.

Thanks for the detailed response.  It's not critically important to use a USB; to be honest I mostly wanted to be able to switch it off/on from a microcontroller + mosfet.  Obviously a relay would be an easier choice than all you said, but running from USB seems to offer a side effect of being able to run from a powerbank, and reduces the amount of messy wires running around -- I generally like to avoid messing around with AC mains power.

May I ask please, would I not be able to simply replace the piezo element with a lower-voltage one?  Or is that simply not how piezos work?  Alternatively I even considered using one of those 8ohm speakers as they seem to have a nice diaphragm.  (Ironic, using a speaker to make a "silent" pump, but it could be run at 15hz or so..)

Gee, I don't know.  Please provide some information about the fan you have.
